# CLR function to parse MDX string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, t-sql

I'm looking to be able to take an MDX string like this:

```
[Event Product].[Event Category Filter].[Category Group].&[E].&[F].&[G].&[H]
```

And to use regex to *individually* parse out the first, second and third strings between the square brackets.

So, ideally three custom regex expressions that would return:

```
Event Product

Event Category Filter

Category Group
```

The fourth grouping and onward can be optional (although the first three will always be present). It would be great to have a fourth expression capable of returning every subsequent match after in a delimited one-liner, so something like:

```
E,F,G,H
```

I've captured the first group:

```
((?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\]))
```

However I'm struggling with the nth exclusions piece.

Would anyone be able to lend a hand here? :)

**Edit:**

Should've mentioned this upfront, we're using regex assembly script and doing this in vanilla T-SQL.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

A C# solution is what I'd ultimately want to use, but a pure regex solution for the time being would work best. I work mostly with a non-dot net stack so we don't have a full tool kit at our disposal as far as our ETL goes, unfortunately.

Comment: What characters are allowed between the square brackets?

Comment: SQL Server Analysis Services seems to only allow alphanumeric, _, - and spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a C# class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;

namespace ExtractMdxParts
{
    public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
    {
        public class EventData
        {
            public SqlString Product;
            public SqlString CategoryFilter;
            public SqlString Group;
            public SqlString ExtraData;
        }

        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
        FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
        TableDefinition = "Product nvarchar(128), CategoryFilter nvarchar(128), Group nvarchar(128), Extradata nvarchar(MAX)",
        IsDeterministic = true)]

        public static IEnumerable ExtractParts([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] String MdxString)
        {
            string[] parts = MdxString.Split(".".ToCharArray(), 4, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (parts.Length < 3)
            {
                return null;
            }

            List<EventData> x = new List<EventData> { };
            char[] trimChars = "[]".ToCharArray();
            EventData y = new EventData { Product = parts[0].Trim(trimChars), CategoryFilter = parts[1].Trim(trimChars), Group = parts[2].Trim(trimChars) };

            if (parts.Length == 4)
            {
                y.ExtraData = string.Join(",", parts[3].Split(".".ToCharArray()).Select(p => p.Substring(1).Trim(trimChars)));
            }

            x.Add(y);

            return x;

        }

        public static void FillRow(object eventData, out SqlString product, out SqlString categoryFilter, out SqlString group, out SqlString extraData)
        {
            //I'm using here the EventData class defined above
            EventData ed = (EventData)eventData;
            product = new SqlString(ed.Product.ToString());
            categoryFilter = new SqlString(ed.CategoryFilter.ToString());
            group = new SqlString(ed.Group.ToString());
            extraData = new SqlString(ed.ExtraData.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

And add it into SQL Server with

```
use [testing]
go

CREATE ASSEMBLY ExtractMdxParts
   FROM 'C:\Your\Path\Here\ExtractMdxParts.dll'
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS

GO

CREATE FUNCTION ExtractParts (@MdxString nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS TABLE (Product nvarchar(128),
                    CategoryFilter nvarchar(128),
                    [Group] nvarchar(128),
                    ExtraData nvarchar(MAX)
                    )
   AS EXTERNAL NAME [ExtractMdxParts].[ExtractMdxParts.UserDefinedFunctions].ExtractParts
GO
```

where 'testing' is the name of your database and you do all the fiddly bits to allow CLR procedures...

then you can do things like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExtractParts(N'[a].[b].[c].&[e].&[f]')
```

and get a table like

```
Product CategoryFilter  Group   ExtraData
-----------------------------------------
a       b               c       e,f
```

Important parts I had to use to make it work:

- `using System.Collections;` so that you can `public static IEnumerable ExtractParts...`
- `new SqlString(...` may not be vital, but I was getting desperate with "because T-SQL and CLR types for ... do not match"
- I didn't go the way of a signed assembly because VS wouldn't let me sign the assembly and didn't give a meaningful error message to me so I did the brute-force `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::testing TO [computername\accountname]`. Use signing: I'm only writing this as an answer to the question; you will have more time to shout at VS without the neighbours complaining.
- another possibly-not-required thing is `[SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]` which comes out of [something](http://dataeducation.com/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable/) written by Adam Machanic. But if *he* writes it, it is very probably a Good Idea.

Oh... and I used SQL Server 2014 in conjuction with .NET 4.5.2 in VS2015 Community Edition.

I tested it as working with the following data:

> [].[bhgshsfhsf].[chhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh].&[qwert].&[asd].&[tyu].&[].&vbncmzxvb]
>   [a134141].[bhgshsfhsf].[chhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh].&[qwert].&[asd].&[tyu].&[].&vbncmzxvb]
>   [a134141].[bhgshsfhsf].[chhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh]
>   [a].[b].[c]

It returns `NULL` for the `ExtraData` column if there is no extra data.

It fails if `NULL` is passed to it, and gives an empty string for every column if an empty string is passed to it. This may or may not be a problem to you.

Reference: [Introduction to SQL Server CLR table valued functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2582/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-table-valued-functions/)

Comment: This is absolutely incredible, Andrew. Thanks for taking the time to not only write the elegant code for my *exact* use case, but also for very clearly explaining how to create an assembly from scratch and to ultimately implement it as a user-defined function. +1 for teaching me an incredibly useful feature of .NET!

Comment: @dgills You're welcome - it's a long time since I wrote a CLR function. I did not test it extensively, as it was late when I got it working. Also, maybe a better title for your question would be "CLR function to parse MDX string" - it might help people with searches.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what you want, using what you already have. Hopefully this snippet of code can help you.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string linetoparse = "[Event Product].[Event Category Filter].[Category Group].&[E].&[F].&[G].&[H]";

        DoIt(linetoparse);
    }

    private void DoIt(string linetoparse)
    {
        string pattern = @"((?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\]))";//the pattern you are looking for
        MatchCollection matches = null;//initialize a variable to hold your matches

        if (Regex.IsMatch(linetoparse, pattern))//If there is at least 1 match
        {
            matches = Regex.Matches(linetoparse, pattern);//store the matches in our storage variable
        }

        if (matches != null)
        {
            string match1 = ((Match)matches[0]).ToString();//Event Product
            string match2 = ((Match)matches[1]).ToString();//Event Category Filter
            string match3 = ((Match)matches[2]).ToString();//Category Group
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is beautiful and works perfectly, thank you! :) Our shop has .NET apps running several of our processes, but this particular project was scripted out in vanilla T-SQL using a regex assembly library. I ultimately want to use this though.